# Open a moviefile with a keypress in Applescript

Tags: applescript, quicktime, movie

I am currently working on a school project in which I need to open a video file while using a key press in applescript. I want the program to open the file fullscreen in quicktime player when I press "y" while the program is running.

This is my current code, it works but I don't see how I can include keypresses.

```
tell application "QuickTime Player"
    set testmovie to "Users:Nan:movies:atime.mp4"
    activate
    open alias testmovie
    play document 1
    set presenting of document 1 to true
end tell
```

I hope you guys can help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can create a Service in Automator and paste your code within a run applescript action. You can then assign a keystroke to the service in keyboard preferences.